# Including a file outside the web space

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to hide MySQL database connections settings outside of `public_html` to be accessed  using `require_once()`. I'm using a hosting company.

When I use `phpinfo()` I'm told that the include_path is `usr/local/lib/php` however I can see no such directory within my account.

From what I have read I should be able to use

```
ini_set("include_path","../config");
```

to assign the include path temporarily to a folder called "config" parallel to the `public_html` folder.

I had then expected the following to work, but it didn't

```
require_once("hello.php");
```

Should I try a different approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can always require using a relative path like `__DIR__ . '/../config/hello.php`

Answer (score 1):

Just pointing out that there would be no use to moving your database connection info outside of the public_html. Anyone who would be able to read it inside your public_html, would be able to read it outside the public_html. The thing about PHP is it doesn't transmit PHP source code, only the output; so assuming that you are just printing the database connection info via `echo 'CONNECTION INFO'` then no one will be able to read it (that is unless there's a vulnerability in your system that lets people print the contents of files).

Comment: Thanks. I assumed that should someone find 'file.php' then they would be able to see the php code inside.